# How to make ethereum sync keep fast?

Tags: synchronization, ethereum

There is a geth on my server,and synchronization complete.

However sometimes,geth will delay to sync it for 1-2 minutes when a new block found.

Why?Network delay?Bad peers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your peers - how many peers you have, how good your peers are, etc. If you look at https://ethstats.net/ some nodes have over 400 peers.

So if you want to improve your node, I recommend increasing the peers limit.

Personally, however, I would recommend against running your own eth node. I have tried it and was difficult to have the server node running **reliably**. It is a lot easier and much more reliable to use a service like Infura - https://infura.io/

Comment: Thank you so much!
I 'll try to increase my peers limit.
And using service doesn't suit us very well,because peer on our server is convenient for us to adjust.

Comment: If you are going to hose your own geth node, I would recommend to 1) host several nodes and use a load balancer to pick the "healthiest" one
and 2) use a mix of different clients - geth, parity, etc, to prevent ethereum network DoS attacks that target a specific client